# Expand and hide a div on click and expand one at a time

Tags: jquery

I want to expand a div at a time AND expand/hide the div on click. In other words, when one div is open the other should be closed and both div can be open at the same time.

This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide the tooglebox when page load
    $(".togglebox").hide();
    //slide up and down when click over heading 2
    $(".toggletxt").click(function(){
    // slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
    $(this).next(".togglebox").slideToggle("slow");
    return true;
    });
    });
```

This code will hide both div (togglebox) and expand on click to toogletxt. But both div can be expanded if I click on its toogletxt.

Comment: do you mean like an accordion?

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense. You say that you want one to collapse when the other is opened...but they can both be open at the same time.

Comment: Please try to clarify what you are trying to do here... your description of your issue was tough to understand

Comment: You want to show 2 div's at the same time, but you also want to hide the second div when the first is clicked ? is that correct ? Like " I want to have 2 girlfriends at the same time and the other one should disapear when I click the other one" :D just kidding :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".togglebox").hide();
$(".toggletxt").click(function() {
    var me = this;
    $('.togglebox').hide(function() {
        $(me).next(".togglebox:hidden").slideToggle("slow");
    })
});
```